# Failed binder transaction in android widget

Tags: java, android, android-widget

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [failed binder transaction on widget update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888890/failed-binder-transaction-on-widget-update)

i am having a problem when i try to update a bitmap in my android widget. JAVA FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION error start looping in my logcat after 10 to 12 updates of bitmap and my widget stop updating after that. All i am doing is showing current seconds in my widget at the moment.
This is how i am creating a bitmap

```
public static Bitmap buildUpdate(String time,Context ctx) 
    {
Bitmap myBitmap=null;   
    myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(160, 84, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Typeface clock = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(),"AladinRegular.ttf");
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setSubpixelText(true);
    paint.setTypeface(clock);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setTextSize(65);
    paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
    myCanvas.drawText(time, 80, 60, paint);
    return myBitmap;
    }
```

and this is where i am calling it to update my imageview

```
   remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.label_fg, Drawing.buildUpdate(seconds+" ",ctxt));
```

I dont know what i seem to be doing wrong here , all i got after two days of research is that i am hitting IPC memory limit. Why so and how to avoid this ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're hitting the size limit for bitmaps passed through a binder call. More recent versions of Android use newer mechanisms for this and the limits are higher.

You can avoid the error by using smaller bitmaps. :)

Comment: but making a smaller bitmap only delays the error , it does not avoid this :/