# javabinder , FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION - setImageViewBitmap(..)

Tags: android, clock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [failed binder transaction on widget update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888890/failed-binder-transaction-on-widget-update)

### Whenever I update my widget Imageview using the bitmap, the Logcat shows the following error,

### "Javabinder , FAILED  BINDER TRANSACTION"

I searched in the internet and understood that it is due to memory issue.

I am using the following code to update the ImageView.

```
private void update(Context context) {
    Log.d("Configure", "updatestart");
    remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.clockview,
            buildUpdate("CURRENTTIME", c));
    awm.updateAppWidget(awID, remoteViews);
}
```

And the buildUpdate function:

```
public Bitmap buildUpdate(String time, Context context) {


    Log.d("ConfigureApp","Buildupdate_fn ---" + "start");
    date = new Date();
    sec = (float) date.getSeconds();
    min = (float) date.getMinutes();
    hour = (float) date.getHours() + min / 60.0f;

    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 200, Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    p.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
    p.setStrokeWidth(2);
    canvas.drawLine(
            x,
            y,
            (float) (x + (r - 15)
                    * Math.cos(Math
                            .toRadians((hour / 12.0f * 360.0f) - 90f))),
            (float) (y + (r - 10)
                    * Math.sin(Math
                            .toRadians((hour / 12.0f * 360.0f) - 90f))), p);
    canvas.save();
    p.setColor(0xFF0000FF);
    canvas.drawLine(
            x,
            y,
            (float) (x + r
                    * Math.cos(Math.toRadians((min / 60.0f * 360.0f) - 90f))),
            (float) (y + r
                    * Math.sin(Math.toRadians((min / 60.0f * 360.0f) - 90f))),
            p);
    canvas.save();
    p.setColor(0xFFA2BC13);
    canvas.drawLine(
            x,
            y,
            (float) (x + (r + 10)
                    * Math.cos(Math.toRadians((sec / 60.0f * 360.0f) - 90f))),
            (float) (y + (r + 15)
                    * Math.sin(Math.toRadians((sec / 60.0f * 360.0f) - 90f))),
            p);

    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.mycity, Float.toString(x));
    return bitmap;
}
```

Please tell me how to avoid this error.:( Is there any other way to do the same?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

If this is memory error, then try to reuse the bitmap, instead of creating the new on every time `buildUpdate()` is called.

Also, AFAIK, `canvas.save()` is only useful if you actually call `canvas.restore()`.

Comment: From the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888890/failed-binder-transaction-on-widget-update I understood that we can save it in a folder and just calling will avoid the error. But how to do that?